# Where can I find a world map from the Victorian period?

Tags: maps, victorian

I'm looking for a (preferably open-source) decently quality political map of the world from around 1890 (1885-1900 would be usable for what I want). I don't have a lot of experience looking for maps or other historical documents, and Googling hasn't given me any real information.

So, where should I be looking for a map like this at?

Comment: Are you looking for a map *published* around 1890, or a modern map showing the world in 1890?

Comment: I was looking for a map published around 1890.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are some atlases for 1890 or thereabouts on the internet archive. This one here is exactly 1890.

[The world-wide atlas of modern geography, political and physical, containing one hundred and twelve plates and complete index [cartographic material]](https://archive.org/details/worldwideatlasof00wakj_0)

There are plenty of others at this link (but not necessarily 1890).

https://archive.org/details/normanbleventhalmapcenter

Answer (score 0):

University of Alabama has a large digital collection of historical maps grouped by region and period of publication. [Here](http://alabamamaps.ua.edu/historicalmaps/world/1876-1900.html) are the world maps for 1876-1900, and it's a long list with thumbnail images and publication details. But unfortunately, the image links don't work! It's really a shame this site is not maintained but with some searching you may be able to track down images on archive.org or elsewhere.

Here are a few other sites with searchable collections of historical maps, and some relevant examples I found on each with just a quick search.

- http://www.historicmapworks.com/

  - [The World Chart, revised 1887](http://www.historicmapworks.com/Map/WM/1512/The+World+Chart///)
  - [The World Map, 1893](http://www.historicmapworks.com/Map/WM/2316/The+World+Map///)
- https://www.davidrumsey.com/

  - [World in Mercator's Projection, 1886](https://www.davidrumsey.com/luna/servlet/detail/RUMSEY~8~1~209631~5003616:World-in-Mercator-s-Projection-?)
  - [World Mercator Projection, 1890](https://www.davidrumsey.com/luna/servlet/detail/RUMSEY~8~1~30552~3000130:World-Mercator-proj-?)

Comment: `Here are the world maps for 1876-1900` great, but clicking anywhere on this website gives me an error message "bad request".

Comment: @Bregalad Yes, I mentioned this problem in my answer. If you see something promising on there you can try searching elsewhere for it based on the details.